# I installed Kali linux and configured Grub2 using EasyBcd. When I try to boot into Kali ay the start I get an error 0xc0000225

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub

I am using Windows 10

Windows Boot Manager error windows failed to start

File: \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr

Status : 0xc0000225

Info : The application or operating system couldn't be loaded beacuse a required file is missing or contains errors.

Also EasyBcd crashed when i tried to register as Grub2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using some sort of mix between WIndows Boot Loader and Grub ist the reason why you are not able to start Kali.

Do the following, install GRUB as your default GRUB Loader. You can do that by using any LIVE-DVD such as Rescatux. Then rebuild your GRUB-Menu. Grub will also detect a windows-partition and create a new entry for WIndows.